# Small SOHO Router with 3+ Gigabit SFP ports

Tags: router

Is there a reasonably priced (below 250$ USD) router with 3 or more Gigabit SFP ports for SOHO that can handle a Gigabit WAN uplink?

Something like Mikrotik CRS106-1C-5S https://mikrotik.com/product/CRS106-1C-5S but as I understand this CRS is a "smart switch" and doesn't have enough routing capabilities.

[image: Cloud Router Switch]

Comment: That MikroTik has RouterOS L5 - so it has all the routing possibilities you might need in SOHO, but the CPU might bottleneck you

Comment: Would building your own be an option you're comfortable with?

Comment: @JMY1000 Yes, it would be alright, but I really don't know of any way to do so, I thought even designing a router would cost up to thousands of USD, yet alone building one. Can you explain?

Comment: I'd have to look into what hardware exactly, but there appear to be plenty of expansion cards with dual SFPs; you could use them in conjunction with a normal computer/server (if you can find one with enough expansion) and pfSense/OPNsense and create your own switch. Only issue I really have is distinguishing hardware that'll work for standard IP vs. Fibre Channel. Out of curiosity, why do you have SFPs instead of RJ45 for "only" gigabit? I understand the uplink ofc, but the other ones are a little confusing to me.